# c++/c data structures for storing strings separated by blanks

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

What is the best data structures for storing
strings separated by blanks

the variable peers contains a list of strings separated by blanks
Each such a string has the form host:port, where host is a host name (DNS name or IP in dotted decimal notation2) and port is a positive number.

in the list i may have something like
127.0.0.1:8080 127.3.0.1:9080 127.0.0.1:3000 127.3.0.1:9080

what's the best way to deal with these kind of data,
any code example for
create this variable "peers"

Comment: C or C++? Both are different (therefore, both will have different procedures to achieve the way). Also, you want to separate host:port to different variables?

Comment: I think literally any collection (of strings) would qualify. Or did you mean how to parse?

Comment: @RohanBari hi Rohan everything is stored in a variable called peers, c++ and c both are ok as long as i can handle this

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>    

std::stringstream iss { str };
std::vector<std::string> peers;

std::string tmp;
while (iss >> tmp)
    peers.push_back(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are only correct IP addresses and port numbers in the individual parts, they are no longer than 21 characters and the data could therefore be saved as an array of (fixed-length) strings:

```c
char peers[][21] = {"127.0.0.1:8080", "127.3.0.1:9080", "127.0.0.1:3000", "127.3.0.1:9080"};
```

The advantage of this variant would be that the entries can be accessed directly via an array index:

```c
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    printf("%s\n", peers[i]);
```

Comment: The question says "*DNS name or* IP" so the assumption behind this answer is probably unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best data structures for storing strings separated by
> blanks

It all depends how you are going to access this data. Are you going call it by some sort of ID? If yes, you might use map for sorted data or unordered map without sorting it. Are you going to access elements using id? Then maybe vector will suffice. Is number of string known before you start? Think about using array. About access, you can keep all the data inside one string and simply know which blank is which IP. You can also parse strings and save them into array/vector. If you want to access data not by ID but by it's value (while making sure it's inside container) make key it's value and use set. If you want to keep these inside container, don't access by id, you don't know how many items you will hold, might use list or forward_list. It's all up to how data will be processed.